# Не получается сделать сохранение Text через JsonUtility в Unity

Tags: c#, json, unity3d

Я новичок в вопросах программирования и мне захотелось сделать простое приложение на Unity, используя c#.

Основная моя идея уже реализована, но я не могу сделать сохранение в своём приложение.

Не могли бы вы посмотреть мой код и подсказать что не так?

Вот то, что сохраняется в json файле `{"Foodtext":{"instanceID":0}}`

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Mane : MonoBehaviour{  

public GameObject ShowText;
public GameObject Info;

public InputField Food;
public InputField Medicaments;

private Save save = new Save();  
private string path; //Путь к файлу json

public Text ShowFood; //текст, который будет потом показывать сохраненный 
текст из InputField
public Text Foodtext; //текст, вводимый в InputField, который нужно сохранить
public Text ShowMedicaments;
public Text Medicamentstext;



    public void Start()
    {
    #if UNITY_ANDROID && !UNITY_EDITOR
        path = Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, "Save.json");
    #else
        path = Path.Combine(Application.dataPath, "Save.json");
    #endif
        if (File.Exists(path))
        {
            save = JsonUtility.FromJson<Save>(File.ReadAllText(path));
            Debug.Log("Nice!");
        }  else Debug.Log("No");
    }

    public void SaveText()
    {
        save.Foodtext.text = Foodtext.text;

    }

    #if UNITY_ANDROID && !UNITY_EDITOR    
    private void OnApplicationPause(bool pause)
    {
        if (pause) File.WriteAllText(path, JsonUtility.ToJson(save));
    } 

    #endif
    public void OnApplicationQuit()
    {
        File.WriteAllText(path, JsonUtility.ToJson(save));
    }    




    public void OK()
    {
        Info.SetActive (false);
        ShowText.SetActive (true);

        ShowFood.text = Foodtext.text;
        ShowMedicaments.text = Medicamentstext.text + "₽";

    }

    public void Edit()
    {
        Info.SetActive (true);
        ShowText.SetActive (false);
        Foodtext.text = ShowFood.text;
        Medicamentstext.text = ShowMedicaments.text + "₽";
    }

    [Serializable]
    public class Save
    {
        public Text Foodtext;


    }
```

Comment: Ваш вопрос непонятен, объясните пожалуйста подробнее вот какие моменты. Вы хотите реализовать сохранение - сохранение чего? Чем не нравится содержимое файла? У вас корректный json, описания класса Text нет, но я примерно представляю что там написано -- и с точки компьютера вполне понятно, что он сделал именно то, что вы просили. А что хотели-то попросить сделать? Задача в чём состоит? Сохранить что? Сохранить как?

Answer (score 0):

Я не думаю, что вы вот так в лоб можете сохранить инстанс компонента `Text`. Вернее, он вам сериализуют только сериализуемые поля (по дефолту, вероятно, сериализуется только `instanceID`).

`JsonUtility` вообще предназначен для простейших DTO классов без всяких ссылочных зависимостей.

В вашем случае вообще можно в `PlayerPrefs` это запихать.

```
#if UNITY_ANDROID && !UNITY_EDITOR    
private void OnApplicationPause(bool pause)
{
    if (pause) 
        PlayerPrefs.SetString("save", save.Foodtext.text);
} 

#endif
public void OnApplicationQuit()
{
    PlayerPrefs.SetString("save", save.Foodtext.text);
}  

public void Start()
{
    if(save != null && save.Foodtext != null)
        save.Foodtext.text = PlayerPrefs.GetString("save", "");
}
```

Если класс `Save` будет добавлено куда больше полей, то свой мапер напишите, если хотите, всё же, `JsonUtility` использовать.

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ, попробую через PlayerPrefs и потом зашифрую данные, чтобы защититься от взлома)